# Shift Register in Top Design for PSoC 6

Tags: shift-register, psoc

How can I implement a Shift Register in the top design of PSoC Creator for a PSoC 6? In the Component Catalog in PSoC Creator I cannot find the component for a shift register.

My goal is to be able to create a 19-bit shift register with the same settings as these in the figure using in a project with a PSoC 3 CY8C3246PVI-147 as target device.

The same component is incompatible by selecting the PSoC 6 CY8C6347BZI-BLD53 as target device.

[image: Shift Register implementation with PSoC 3 as target device]

[image: Shift Register options]

[image: Shift Register implementation with PSoC 6 as target device]